# Set a flag on rows having a certain value in an array field

Tags: parse-platform

I have a collection of posts, and for each posts I've added 2 array fields to keep track of the users who upvoted and downvoted the post.

Given a logged user, when I query the collection of posts, I would like to know for each post if the user has either upvoted or downvoted.

Note that I do not want to filter posts by upvote and downvote - I want all posts, just a flag on each post, so that I can highlight each post with an upvote or downvote icon.

My understanding is that this is not possible using queries on array values (`whereKey:equalTo:` in iOS SDK), because that filters posts, whereas I need them all.

The only workaround I can think of is to make 2 distinct queries, one without filter, the other returning the rows for which the user has upvoted/downvoted, and then combining the 2 result sets at client side.

Is there any better way of doing that, preferably in a single query?

Otherwise, would I have any advantage if I move the 2 arrays to a separate class/collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot set flags on Parse Objects. To accomplish this, you need two queries. You can query for all the comments, and then query for the the posts that the user has either liked or disliked. [Link](https://www.parse.com/questions/add-a-flag-to-a-parse-query-result-to-indicate-if-the-user-is-contained-in-the-like-relation-ios)

Comment: That might work for a single post, but I need to gather that flag when retrieving all posts to display in a list

Comment: Why can't you call the query for each post? In my app, I call the query, update the look of the cell, and then set the state in cache. This is done for each cell.

Comment: You could pass the object id's of all the posts to a cloud code function, which returns an array of their like statuses.

Comment: That's an option, but it's pretty much the same as using `whereKey:equalTo:`

Comment: Then write a function that returns the flags for all the posts (object id & status).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60566/discussion-between-dehli-and-antonio).

Answer (score 0):

A better option is to use the single query to get all the records, then use a simple loop to add a flag client-side.

Showing that the current user has up/down voted is a UI concern, trying to use the database for that task is not appropriate.

If written correctly your loop should also be much faster that running a second query.

Comment: Well, the 2nd query seems needed to know if the user voted or not. I didn't mention in the question, but I think it's implicit that I do NOT want to download the content of the 2 arrays, because they can grow a lot